# MySQL joins: why is this returning a row?

Tags: mysql, database, join

I have the below query. The email and pass specified do NOT correspond to any row in the table, so it should return no rows, which is what happens.

```
        SELECT *
        FROM _users
        LEFT JOIN _assocs ON
            item_id = _users.id AND
            item_type = "_users.user_group" AND
            foreign_item_type = "_user_groups"
        WHERE
            email = 'some@email.com' AND
            password = 'somepass' AND
            activation_key IS NULL
        LIMIT 1
```

However, when I modify the `SELECT` part to

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(foreign_item_id) AS user_groups
```

...it always returns a row, regardless, with the columns all having null values. Why?

I'm using a left join specifically because it's possible nothing will be returned from table 2 (_assocs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `group_concat()` is an aggregation function (such as `MIN()`, `MAX()`, `SUM()` and `AVG()`).

This turns the query into an aggregation query, with no `group by` clause.  For such a query, all the rows are considered as a single set and one row is returned to summarize them.  These is even true when the result set has no rows.  As you have found, the result is one row with `NULL`s in the columns.

Comment: Can't beLIEVE I forgot the `group by`. Well, it is midnight on a Saturday. Thanks dude.

Answer (score 0):

According to [mysql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat), when no non-null value is provided for `GROUP_CONCAT` function, the return value is null,

Comment: Yes, but I don't think this explains overall why it returns a row, given I'm using a left join. I think Gordon below nailed it. Thanks for the answer anyway.